# (intermediate value).error is not a function - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I'm calling a method inside WebApi 2 controller everything is working as expected however when I check the developer console I see the following error message:

`Error: (intermediate value).error is not a function`

Now I've done the research and some people have said: You're missing a closing semi colon within your method, however I've gone through my code and I can't see anywhere that I'm missing this.

My Angular Js login function:

```
 $scope.Login = function () {

    var emailAddress = $scope.emailAddress.trim();
    var password = $scope.password.trim();

    var valid = loginApi(emailAddress, password);

};
```

Which calls this function:

```
  function loginApi(emailAddress, password) {

    var login = { "EmailAddress": emailAddress, "Password": password };

    $http.post("/api/Login/", login).success(function (data, status) {
        alert('success');
    }
    .error(function (error, status) {
        alert(error);
    }));

};
```

Comment: @MikeS you're not wrong it worked, put that as the answer and I'll mark it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but don't you need a closing parenthesis after your .success function and then remove one at the end of the .error?

```
$http.post().success(function() {}).error(function() {});
```

Otherwise it would seem like you're enclosing your error in your success.

The other thing to think about is that in Angular both .success and .error have been deprecated and they suggest using then:
[Angular API: $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.